# jquery code ceases to work when hosted by an external source

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs, jquery-tabs

So I have this jquery code which switches tabs in a div when I click on them... I need to host the javascript on an external source, and i've called it in like this:

```
<script src="(link here).js?auto></script>
```

And i know it runs because it sets the tabs up properly, but it doesn't switch them. When I click on the tab it opens "http:// #tab1/" instead of "http:// (mywebsite).com/#tab1/"

Here is my code:

```
$(function () {
$('div.tabgroup').each(function () {
    var $active, $content, $links = $(this).find('a');
    $active = $($links.filter('[href="' + location.hash + '"]')[0] || $links[0]);
    $active.addClass('active');
    $content = $($active.attr('href'));
    $links.not($active).each(function () {
        $($(this).attr('href')).hide()
    });
    $(this).on('click', 'a', function (e) {
        $active.removeClass('active');
        $content.hide();
        $active = $(this);
        $content = $($(this).attr('href'));
        $active.addClass('active');
        $content.show();
        e.preventDefault()
    })
})
});
```

How can I make it so it add's the current website url before the link?
A live demo of it can be seen here: http://test-theme-one.tumblr.com/test

Comment: i don't know what you were having trouble with,but tabs are working fine for me.

Comment: The tabs, yes but not their content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/mAuRG/

I applied a class to each of the content areas to simply things.
HTML:

```
<div class="tabgroup"><a href="#home1">#home1</a></div>
<div class="tabgroup"><a href="#home2">#home2</a></div>
<div class="tabgroup"><a href="#home3">#home3</a></div>
<div class="tabgroup"><a href="#home4">#home4</a></div>
<div class="tabgroup"><a href="#home5">#home5</a></div>

<div id="home1" class="content-area">This is #home1's Content</div>
<div id="home2" class="content-area">This is #home2's Content</div>
<div id="home3" class="content-area">This is #home3's Content</div>
<div id="home4" class="content-area">This is #home4's Content</div>
<div id="home5" class="content-area">This is #home5's Content</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
    var $tabs = $('div.tabgroup'),
        $links = $tabs.find('a'),
        $active = function(){
                var ret = $links.eq(0);
                $links.each(function(){
                    if ($(this).attr('href') == location.hash){
                        ret = $(this);
                    }
                });
                return ret;
            }(),
        $contentAreas = $('.content-area'),
        $activecontent = $($active.attr('href'));

    $active.addClass('active');
    $contentAreas.hide();
    $activecontent.show();

    $tabs.on('click','a',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $active = $(this);
        $activecontent = $($active.attr('href'));

        $links.removeClass('active');
        $active.addClass('active');

        $contentAreas.hide();
        $activecontent.show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues:

**1. Tabs not switching content when clicked**

Your tabs does not switch the content since they have URLs like `http://.one`, but not `.one` as you expect. So, to fix the issue you should remove `http://` from the link URL. One of the ways to do it is replace

```
$(this).attr('href')
```

with

```
$(this).attr('href').split(/https?:\/\//).pop()
```

which will remove `http://` and `https://` from link URLs in case they do have such prefix.

**2. You can't navigate to specific tab using hash**

First of all expression `$links.filter('[href="' + location.hash + '"]')[0]` will return link with href `#one` for the URL `http://test-theme-one.tumblr.com/test#one`, that means that your links should be like `<a href="#one">...</a>` and not like `<a href="http://.one">...</a>` and your content should be `<div id="one"></div>`, but not `<div class="one"></div>`.

If you do want to use classes instead of ids for content than you should remove `#` from location hash (something like `location.hash.substring(1)`) and use links like `<a href="#.one">...</a>`

**Conclusion**

Finally your html should be:

```
<div class="tabgroup">
    <a href="#one"></a>
    <a href="#two"></a>
    <a href="#three"></a>
    <div class="comment">
        <div id="one">...</div>
        <div id="two">...</div>
        <div id="tree">...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and your JavaScript:

```
$(window.onhashchange = function () {
    var hash = location.hash || $('.tabgroup a:first').attr('href');
    $('.tabgroup a').
        removeClass('active').
        find('[href="' + hash + '"]').
        addClass('active');
    $('.tabgroup .comment>div').
        hide().
        find(hash).
        show();
});
```

**P.S.**

And by the way, you can implement tabs without JavaScript at all, just take a look at `:target` CSS selector. Here http://css-tricks.com/css3-tabs/ you can find how to do it :)

Comment: Updated my demo... First it groups all the tabs and then you have to click each one to get it to show it's own content... not the behavior I expected

Comment: I think the problem is that since it is hosted externally it doesn't known which website to add the "/.one" to. Is their a way to add the current website url to my original jquery code?

Comment: @dsherv `location.origin + location.pathname` will give you full path to your site (including app/folder name)